# Rejection of text containing SQL statements

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, sql

OK, I've been having weird problems for the last 1/2 hour trying to [post an answer to a database-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490422/invoking-ado-net-from-matlab) on StackOverflow, and I keep getting this result (on Firefox 3.6)

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
>          moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network
>          connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure
>          that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.

The problem seems to occur when I try to post some code with 'd--- table' in it, where 'd---' is replaced by the word drop.

I cannot post the following 3 lines, in either SO or this site, if they include the well-known SQL statements DROP.

```
stat.executeUpdate('d--- table if exists people;');
stat.executeUpdate('create table people (name, occupation);');
prep = conn.prepareStatement(...
    'insert into people values (?, ?);');
```

test again:

```
'dro* table'
'drop ball'
drop the table
drop fable
drop    t*ble
droptable
```

drop a table

The evil words for me are "drop" and "table"... how come you guys can post? :(

**edit:** Could someone please suggest another online site that is not stackoverflow that is a quick way to try out a POST request of a text field?

**UPDATE:** Never mind. I don't know what the answer is, but the same problem occurs on Google's website. So it's not stackoverflow. Now to go to my IT Dept...

Comment: How come you can't?

Comment: I have no @#%@#%@%@$%ing clue.

Comment: I can't even post "drop *able" in a comment

Comment: I can post "drop" and "table" separately but not together. WTF????

Comment: I can post drop table

Comment: @Jason: Have you tried with another browser?

Comment: I suppose it *could* be rep-based, but if so, I would have thought the threshold would be 2000 or below. Perhaps it's Firefox trying to keep its users from hacking?

Comment: @fretje: That just occured to me as well, now trying with Safari....

Comment: Oh @mmy! that would be too altruist for its own good in Firefox's part.

Comment: safari: "drop" and "table" but not together

Comment: Won't work with Safari either. I am starting to suspect an evil and incompetent corporate firewall on my end.

Comment: Firefox 3.0.18 -- Little Bobby'); -- drop table students;

Comment: IE 7.0: "drop" and "table" but not together.

Comment: Same problem on IE 7.0... looks like it's not the browser but somewhere between the internet connection and SO's server.

Comment: What if you set up a proxy in your browser, which might fool the server into thinking you have another IP address?

Comment: Seems like your IT department wants you not to do *bad* stuff. I wonder if it is in place out of a  misplaced sense of *security*.

Comment: Once you find out what in the world your IT department is doing, post it on thedailywtf.com, sounds like it would make a clbuttic story.

Comment: @Aaronaught - this would be a great topic for my first article (since I'll be writing for the site soon)... if you want, send it directly to jrasch[ampersat]inedo{dot}com

Comment: drop table (5 more to go)

Comment: drop table students (hey, instead of making sure we don't have s___tons of sql injection vulnerabilities in our software, let's just blacklist "drop table!")

Comment: SO is a programming site, so if I can't include a DROP (the) TABLE command, even if only from certain browsers, there's a serious problem.
SO needs to be changed so that if certain blocked phrases occur, they are obfuscated in the transmitting browser and de-obfuscated at the other end so that the writer's writing is not blocked just because the browser/hardware doesn't like the content.

Comment: @MontyWild -- read the question before commenting. this has nothing to do with SO or browsers; it was something to do with my previous company's internet service provider.

Comment: drop table drop table drop table -- I'm free!!!!! :-)

Comment: Oddly, as we discovered this morning, I got hit with the same issue, but the weird thing is, I'm sure I've said those things other places (I can google "dr*p table", for instance), and odder, while I can't create a question with it, I can create the question, and then *edit* the offending text in. Weird. Anyway, it is still totally the fault of my work filter, nothing to do with SO. (Edit: apparently that is not the case of comments; I can't edit the word dr*p into this comment, either. It's only "dr*p", "table" is fine. Super weird.)

Comment: [I had the same issue!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226237/232835).  Wish I would have found this post first.  Upvotes all around.

Comment: Did any of you figure out the cause? I have changed jobs since my original post and can no longer reproduce.

Comment: @JasonS there's no single cause - each company might use a different security software, and each security software can decide to block any outgoing request on a whim. You win security, you lose the ability to use the internet properly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this exact same problem last week, with the exact same symptoms. Unfortunately I deleted my own question once I found the cause, and realized it wasn't SO related, so I can't link to it.

The problem isn't with SO, you have some kind of filtering software on your network that is sniffing out SQL Injection attempts and it is getting caught and rejected at the network level. If you want to confirm this, you can try typing the same words into Google, Bing or Yahoo and I bet you will get the same error.

In our case it was the Intrusion Protection Module of our Cisco firewall that had a blacklist with several SQL commands that are especially dangerous.

Comment: thanks. Sounds likely, either at our company or at our company's ISP. Also sounds like some boneheads at Cisco need to have their heads smacked. ("sorry, you can't ever send the words "drop table" in that order over the internet since it could be especially dangerous.") (and at this instant I'm writing from home so I can say them. :p :-)

Comment: I can drop...table Google without error, but not here (with " " instead of "...") in IE10.

Answer (score 7):

There are firewalls that are able to filter the network traffic for SQL keywords and statements (at least Cisco has such features).

A work-around would be to connect to StackOverflow / StackExchange sites using `HTTPS`. Then you should be able to post. This is due to `HTTPS` traffic being encrypted so your SQL statements won't be in human (in this case computer) readable format. The firewall then cannot sniff your posts any longer.

For example just call https://stackoverflow.com/ instead of https://stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: interesting -- sorry, I can't test it anymore, not at the same workplace.