# can't post an answer to a question - repeated "The connection was reset"

Tags: support

I've tried a number of times over the past several days to post an answer to the question [how to take out the first 5 characters in each line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336173/how-to-take-out-the-first-5-characters-in-each-line) and each time I get a 'connection was reset' error. I've tried clearing my history, my cache, my cookies, and using a different browser (regularly use firefox, tried chrome as the alternate) all with no success. Help please....?

Comment: Try posting the same answer here to see if you get the same problem. If you do, then remove parts of the answer line by line until you can post. Then you'll have a better idea of what's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks - that narrowed it down to my "drop" "table" example, and I found more info on this question/discussion: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43466/rejection-of-text-containing-sql-statements