# "An error occured submitting the" (question/answer/comment) when body/title text contains "DROP_TABLE" (without the "_")

Tags: bug

I am getting the following error:

[image: An error occurred submitting your question.]

When I try to post the following text to my existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19414687/1687613 **OR** a new answer to the same question, or even post this text here in Meta (thus the *image* of the text):

[image: Question Text]

The error seems to occur when the text above the line `SELECT bt.* FROM #BaseTable bt   -- Output for debugging - delete in production.` is present.  It worked without error when I didn't include it in my answer.

**EDIT:**

The error appears to be in the top two lines; I can't post even part of them as text:

[image]

I tried posting the two words: "DROP_TABLE" with a space instead of the underscore, in upper or lower case, quoted with code sample quotes or double quotes, in the title or body of a question, answer or comment, and got an error too.

Comment: Copy the answer into your paste buffer, refresh the page, and try reposting the answer.

Comment: I tried that, I tried closing IE and reopening it, none of that sort of thing worked.  It appears that something in the top part of the text is giving the stackexchange software trouble, as I can't even post it *here* as text, let alone on SO.

Comment: Actually, it appears to be in the top two lines - I can't even post them here in a comment even partially.

Comment: I've narrowed it down: A "#" character surrounded by code sample quotes "`" appears to cause the problem.

Comment: Interesting, just tried to post "`#`" in an answer on the formatting sandbox; worked just fine. And I seem to be able to post it in a comment too.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be consistent.  `#` works here now.

Comment: DROP -TABLE (without the `-` in ...`ROP TAB`...) doesn't work.

Comment: It isn't because you're using Internet Explorer?

Comment: Considering http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43466/rejection-of-text-containing-sql-statements, and the fact that I *am* using IE, it seems likely.  However, I can put those two words into Google without the problems I get here.

Comment: @MontyWild Google now defaults to https, which can't be filtered by a firewall.

Comment: I can't log into SO or meta via https without getting certificate errors.